# How is an ordered pair (a,b) actually read aloud? An ordered tuple?

Tags: pronunciation

I know what an ordered tuple (e.g. ordered pair) is. I'm not wondering for any reason in particular, but I couldn't find anything on the internet. The question is the title.

I'm usually one to try and give more context but I can't really think of anything else I should say about this one.

Thanks!

Comment: $a$ comma $b$ for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would usually pronounce it "$a$ comma $b$." Other context-dependent variations might include:

- just "$a$ $b$" (if, for example, describing the point $(7,10)$ in the coordinate plane).
- "the ordered pair $a$ $b$," for example the first time such a pair is discussed, or to differentiate it from something else that could also be called "$a$ $b$" or "$a$ comma $b$."
- when defining a mathematical object, e.g. a graph, you might hear "a graph is defined as the pair $V$ $E$ where ..." to refer to the pair of objects $(V,E)$.

In general, though, "$a$ comma $b$" is pretty clear and quite common.